# Unable to Install Microsoft.Net.Http through Nuget

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When trying to installing Microsoft.Net.Http in a Windows Phone 8 project. I'm getting this error:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.4)'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.10'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.3'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.13'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.10' to WinPhone.Data.
Executing script file 'D:\WinPhone\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.10\tools\Install.ps1'.
This reference cannot be removed from the project because it is always referenced by the compiler.
This reference cannot be removed from the project because it is always referenced by the compiler.
This reference cannot be removed from the project because it is always referenced by the compiler.
This reference cannot be removed from the project because it is always referenced by the compiler.
Executing script file 'D:\WinPhone\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.10\tools\Uninstall.ps1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.3'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.10'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Failed to add reference to 'System.IO'
```

It says it's supported for Windows Phone 8 : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.13

Anyone with any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was Nuget; after someone answered this on msdn to update and try again. It worked after that.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 1 version 12.0.30110 with nuget package manager version 2.7.41101.317. Extension manager says I'm up to date. Still cannot install through nuget. I tried 3 times. Note that my target project is targeting netframework40.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2012 with the latest version and latest nuget package manager did allow for installation of Microsoft.Net.Http. The difference between VS2013 and VS2012 was in VS2012, I was appropriately prompted to check out package.config and app.config files where VS2013 never did. I believe this may be why it failed on VS2013.